# Which version of SQL Server 2008 is for development?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

For development which version of SQL Server 2008 should I use?

Comment: SQLServer Express?  It depends on what type of development you are doing.

Comment: which version contain all features in sqlserver 2008?For developement which version need to install express or enterprise or anyother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.  If you need the full features of the Enterprise Edition, you might try the Developer Edition.  That is designed for developers to experience the full set of features in SQL without paying the high costs of getting Enterprise Edition.

Here is a list of the editions and what they are for:

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/mssql_editions.htm

Here is a relevant quote from the above article:

> Developers needing the full features of SQL Server 2008 Enterprise
>   Edition for use in a non-production environment may find SQL Server
>   2008 Developer Edition the right tool for the job. This product has
>   the exact same functionality as Enterprise Edition and only differs in
>   the license. (Oh, and by the way, it's $24,949 cheaper at only $50 per
>   license!) Microsoft also offers a direct upgrade path to convert
>   Developer servers to production licensing.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what type of development you are doing, I would recommend SQL Server 2008 Developer.  However, I usually use Express myself.

**SQL Server 2008 Developer**

> SQL Server 2008 Developer lets developers build any kind of
>   application on top of SQL Server. It includes all the functionality of
>   SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, but is licensed for use as a development
>   and test system, not as a production server. SQL Server 2008 Developer
>   is an ideal choice for people who build and test applications. You can
>   upgrade SQL Server 2008 Developer for production use.

**SQL Server Express**

> The SQL Server Express database platform is based on SQL Server 2008.
>   It is also a replacement for Microsoft Desktop Engine (MSDE).
>   Integrated with Visual Studio, SQL Server Express makes it easy to
>   develop data-driven applications that are rich in capability, secure
>   in storage, and fast to deploy. SQL Server Express is free and can be
>   redistributed by ISV's (subject to agreement). SQL Server Express is
>   ideal for learning and building desktop and small server applications.
>   This edition is the best choice for independent software vendors,
>   non-professional developers, and hobbyists building client
>   applications. If you need more advanced database features, SQL Server
>   Express can be seamlessly upgraded to more sophisticated versions of
>   SQL Server.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

You can get a license "free" with an [MSDN license](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa336270).  You can also get it free through [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) if you are a student.

Answer (score 3):

For such a vague question, the answer is "it depends." Your choices are IMHO:

- **Express Edition** - this edition is free, but lacks many of the features you're probably going to develop for your eventual deployment. Since it is limited in database size, CPU and RAM, it might also be difficult to build your database at all or to adequately test performance.
- **Developer Edition** - this costs about $49 and includes all of the features in Enterprise. The danger here is that if you are deploying to Standard or Workgroup Edition, you won't know when you've used a feature that doesn't work when you deploy.
- **Standard/Workgroup Edition** - probably not the most appropriate for development environment but will ensure that you can only develop features that you will be able to use in production. If you have an MSDN subscription and are deploying to one of these editions, it might be the right choice.